# Combinatorics: Painting squares.

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

[image: grid_of_squares]

I need help with this exercise.

They give you a setup like the one in the picture and they ask,

How many ways can you paint this by painting $6$ squares blue and $9$ red, allowing no row to be completely painted red?

Comment: You might think about the converse: How many ways can you paint the blocks so that 6 are blue, 9 are red, and there is at least one row completely in red?

Comment: You would do well to think about about this problem before asking for help, because that will feed your imagination and intuition for dealing with unfamiliar problems of this type. How are you going to organise the possibilities so you can count them efficiently? What have you thought of yourself? If you rely on someone else's thinking you will have done nothing to develop your own.

Comment: what i did was realize that no row can have 5 blue squares since it wouldn't leave enough for the rest of the rows to have at least one. So the maximum one row can have is 4. Then i started doing cases with that considering the first row having 4 blue squares, then 3, then 2, then 1. Then I added all of those different possibilities. The thing is that this way would probably lead me into making a mistake by forgetting to consider a case, or considering a case twice, etc. So i wanted to know of a better, more organized way. Which is why I asked the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the "painting" we only need to choose which of the 15 squares to paint red (the remaining squares will all be blue)

Without any restrictions, there are 
$\binom{15}{9}$ ways to choose which squares to paint red

If any row is completely red there are $\binom{10}{4} $ ways to paint the remaining 10 squares. We need to subtract these cases for each of the three rows which could be all red.

$$ N_{tot} = \binom{15}{9} -3\binom{10}{4}  $$

Comment: Thanks for the response.